# Flutter - Add pub package in pubspec.yaml

Tags: flutter

I want to add [this package](https://github.com/jeroentrappers/charts) in flutter project. Why this charts? Because it´s have a negative bars

I try to add something like this

```
  charts_flutter:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/jeroentrappers/charts.git
      path: charts/charts_flutter/
      name: charts
      ref: master
```

But return

> Could not find a file named "charts/charts_flutter/pubspec.yaml" in
>   git://github.com/jeroentrappers/charts.git
>   ee7a2110386f7b3e6476eb9ff815c11a65875195.

So what is the correct way to add this type git packages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work

```
 charts_flutter:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/jeroentrappers/charts.git
      path: charts_flutter
      ref: master
```

The path is relative to the repository and `charts_flutter` is a root directory in the repository.
`name` is redundant if it's the same as the dependency itself.

**Update**

In the GitHub repo the charts_flutter `pubspec.yaml` is set up for development and can't be used as Git dependency because it contains a path dependency

```
dependencies:
  charts_common:
    path: ../charts_common/
```

That this dependency can not be overridden by `dependency_overrides` looks like a pub bug to me.

```
dependencies:
  charts_flutter:

dependency_overrides:
  charts_common:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/jeroentrappers/charts.git
      path: charts_common
      ref: master

  charts_flutter:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/jeroentrappers/charts.git
      path: charts_flutter
      ref: master
```

A workaround would be to clone the GitHub repo to a local directory and use a path dependency instead.

```
dependencies:
  charts_flutter:
    path: ../../charts/charts_flutter
```