# dependency_overrides for dependency with path dependency

Tags: flutter, dart, flame

In Flame we have a monorepo with Flame and its bridge packages and all of the bridge packages has Flame as a path dependency (not when they are released). It doesn't seem to be possible to depend on our main branch and on a bridge library on the main branch at the same time, I have this in the `pubspec.yaml` file:

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flame:
    git:
      url: git@github.com:flame-engine/flame.git
      path: packages/flame
      ref: main
  flame_fire_atlas:
    git:
      url: git@github.com:flame-engine/flame.git
      path: packages/flame_fire_atlas
      ref: main

dependency_overrides:
  flame:
    git:
      url: git@github.com:flame-engine/flame.git
      path: packages/flame
      ref: main
```

When doing `pub get` I get:

```
Error on line 15, column 11: Invalid description in the "flame_fire_atlas" pubspec on the "flame" dependency: "../flame" is a relative path, but this isn't a local pubspec.
   ╷
15 │     path: ../flame
   │           ^^^^^^^^
   ╵
pub get failed (65;    ╵)
```

which indicates that the `dependency_override` wasn't used, is it not possible to override path dependencies?

Comment: Does this answer apply to your case? Please check on your end - https://stackoverflow.com/a/54435980/15117201

Comment: We can clone the dependency again of course, but this shouldn't be how `dependency_overrides` work? Do you know if it is documented somewhere, or if there is a bug filed for it?

Comment: Found the related issue: https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/2447

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is a [bug](https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/2447) in pub, the only way to solve it for now is to clone the dependencies that you need to the path that the packages expect them.

So in this case I would have to clone the branch of flame that I want to use to `../flame`, in relation to the projects pubspec file.

Answer (score 0):

see this [this](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/151#issuecomment-1385978523) solution it may help you.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33652246)